# example of inverse limit and direct limit

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module, injective-module, limits-colimits

Does a direct limit of projective need to be projective? And is the inverse limit of injectives injective? I guess they need not, but I can't find an example.

Can you help please?

Comment: Of course not. Every flat module is a direct limit of free modules, but not every flat module is projective.

Comment: yes this is 5.40 of Rotman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his paper "Finitistic dimension...", Bass proved that a ring $R$ has the property that every direct limit of projective modules is projective $\Leftrightarrow R$ is perfect (meaning that every module has a projective cover) $\Leftrightarrow R$ satisfies the descending chain condition on principal ideals $\Leftrightarrow R/J(R)$ is semisimple and $J(R)$ is T-nilpotent (meaning that for any sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq J(R)$ there is some $n$ with $x_1\cdots x_n = 0$).  To be more concrete (although I am not sure how useful this part is), he implicitly shows that $R$ is perfect $\Leftrightarrow$ certain direct limits of countably generated free modules are projective, namely ones of the form $\lim_{n \to \infty} F/G_n$, where $F$ is the free module spanned by $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq R$, and $G_n = \{e_i - x_ie_{i+1}\}_{i=1}^n$.

Answer (score 4):

Neither.

The $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Q}$ is the direct limit of its finitely generated submodules. A finitely generated submodule of $\mathbb{Q}$ is actually infinite cyclic and so free. However $\mathbb{Q}$ is not projective.

So the claim is false even for filtered direct limits.

For inverse limits of injective modules, see [this paper by Bergman on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3173) where it is proved that every module is the inverse limit of injective modules.

Comment: correct. i also wanted to give this answer (about injective), but this is (i think) too complicated for OP; because :1- look at other questions of OP. 2- question is Remark below 7.22 of Rotman. one can expect that there is simpler answer for a remark.

Comment: @user1 It's probably too complicated, but it gives the idea. If you have a simpler example, I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: .If you had a simpler example, I'd be happy to post it :)

Comment: [here](http://www.math-forums.com/inverse-limit-injective-modules-t412272.html) Milne has: **Consider the inverse system indexed by the integers >0 ordered by
divisibility with each group equal to Q/Z; the map from Q/Z (index mn)
to Q/Z (index n) is multiplication by m. The limit is not injective
because it is not divisible (in fact, it is isomorphic to the ring of
finite adeles)**.

Comment: @user1 This seems good; please, post it.

Comment: i should leave.can you please edit your question adding this?

Comment: @user1 Look at the final message in that thread.